# In a `while` loop, why can't I declare variable in the condition as in a `for` loop?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why can't we define a variable inside a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581364/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-a-while-loop)

I would like to simplify the following code:

```
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

into:

```
while ((string line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

but failed.

However, we surely can do this in `for`:

```
for (int i=0, int n=50;i<n;i++)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581364/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-a-while-loop

Comment: I believe with C# 9 you can do this:    while (sr.ReadLine() is { } line)  { .. }

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can still use `for`:

```
for (string line; (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null; )
    ...
```

Comment: 10 years and no one pointed out the fact that this is not an answer to the question asked. The question was why it can't be done in a while-loop, not how it can be done in some other way. The answer below is much better.

Answer (score 12):

Since the `while` loop takes a condition, what this would do is declare a new instance of `line` every time the loop is run, because the condition is evaluated every time through the loop.

It works in a `for` loop because the initializer (the first of the three semicolon-separated expressions) is run only once, at the start; the condition is the second expression. You would have the same problem trying to declare a variable in the condition expression of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

In a for loop:

```
for(<<expr1>>,<<expr2>>,<<expr3>>)
```

The first expression only gets evaluated once.

In a while loop:

```
while(<<expr1>>)
```

The expression gets evaluated on each run through.

It doesn't make sense to redefine the same variable multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason is that you would be declaring the variable multiple times (each pass of the loop).

Asked and answered in more detail here: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581364/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-a-while-loop)