# C# syntax in while loop - no variable definition allowed?

Tags: c#

Please help me to understand why below statement generates compiling error:
Is it wrong to define a variable inside while statement?

```
while((string _l = _sr.ReadLine()) != null){
            _sb.AppendLine(_l);
}
```

//Invalid expression term 'string'

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to declare it outside the loop:

```
string _l;
while((_l = _sr.ReadLine()) != null){
            _sb.AppendLine(_l);
}
```

The specification defines a `while` statement as:

> **8.8.1 The while statement**
>
> while-statement:
>
> while(   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement

Since variable declarations are not boolean expressions, you cannot put them in the condition for a while loop.

Comment: I was thinking of trying to explain why in a comment here, but realized some things. `for` and `foreach` can do it. It's easy enough to say "It was just designed that way," but now I really wonder why.

Comment: I wonder why too!!!!!

Comment: @Magus - The specification defines the form of `while` and `for\foreach` loops separately. `for` loops have an explicit initialiser which can include variable declarations. `foreach` loops can also declare a loop-scored identifier. `while` loop conditions must simply be a `boolean expression`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. "It was designed that way." It didn't *have* to be, though.

Comment: Well, if it was designed that way, you basically end up with two results: either the while loop accepts its own special kind of expression (different from all other expressions) which allows this sort of declaration in it, or variable declarations must themselves be a statement that evaluates to a value.  In that case you could end up stuffing variable declarations into all sorts of weird places that they probably don't belong.

Answer (score 1):

Found similiar question and answer:

"Since the while loop takes a condition, what this would do is declare a new instance of line every time the loop is run, because the condition is evaluated every time through the loop."

[In a `while` loop, why can't I declare variable in the condition as in a `for` loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141666/in-while-why-i-cannot-declare-variable-in-the-condition-just-like-we-do-info)