# Why can't you declare a variable in an if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, variable-declaration

The following is valid in C/C++:

```
if (Foo *foo = MaybeGetFoo())
{
    //Do something with foo.
}
else
{
    //We didn't get foo.
}
```

I end up using this quite a lot. It's a nice shorthand way to access something and do something with it (or deal with the case where `nullptr` was returned). It also limits the scope of `foo` to within the body of the `if`/`else`.

I'm just guessing, but I imagine this works because the assignment operator is returning a `Foo *&`, and then that's being evaluated and compared against zero.

You can't do the same in C#, however; this fails because `'Foo' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`.

```
if ((Foo foo = MaybeGetFoo()) != null)
{
    //Do something.
}
else
{
    //We didn't get foo.
}
```

This is something to do with the declaration of the variable - it doesn't even work using pointers in C#.

For now, the solution is to declare/assign `foo` on the line above, and then assign/evaluate it in the `if` statement (although this means that `foo` will be in the outer scope).

But I'm wondering, what is the compiler expecting in order to believe that `Foo` is being used like a variable? Is there anything in the specification that says that this can't be done?

Comment: Because the specs say so, plus, C# and c/c++  are two different languages.

Comment: Because that's how C# was made?

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581364/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-a-while-loop) out. Answer kinda explains this design choice

Comment: As a workaround you could make your class implement IDisposable and do something like using(Foo foo = MaybeGetFoo()) { if (foo != null) { // Do Something } else { // We didn't get foo } }.  This way foo is only scoped in the using block.